# Validation through jquery fails when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery

My form is set up with some HTML5 to require the fields to be filled in before submission can proceed, but as this isn't supported in < IE10, I need to ensure that those browsers don't allow empty forms to be submitted...

```
<form name="upload" method="post" action="send_form_email3.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div width="100%" class="con3">
        <div class="lable">
            <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
        </div>
        <input  type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="span4" required />

        <div class="lable">
            <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
        </div>
        <input  type="text" name="email" id="email" class="span4" required />

        <div class="lable">
            <label for="telephone">Contact Number *</label>
        </div>
        <input  type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" class="span4" required />

        <div class="lable">
            <label for="comments">Why are you the fun, energetic person that we are looking for? *</label>
        </div>
        <textarea  name="comments" rows="8" id="comments" class="span4" required /></textarea>

        <div class="lable">
            <label for="upload">Send Us Your CV *</label>
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" required />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
</form>
```

To handle this validation on < IE10 (are there any other non-DOM compliant browsers out there? lol), I wrote some jquery.

Mostly the below works on other forms, but this time I thought I might try to improve it a little and loop through the controls with `.each` instead of running a new if statement for each input.

```
$("form[name=upload]").submit(function() {
    // Internet Explorer uses a different call to stop form submission
    // so we need to determine which browser is being used.

    // DOM compliant browsers use HTML5 to do this.

    if ($.browser.msie)
    {
        ($("form[name=upload] input").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "")
            {
                var target, errmsg;
                switch ($(this).attr("name"))
                {
                    case "first_name":
                        errmsg += "Please enter your name.\r\n";
                        break;
                    case "email":
                        errmsg += "Please enter your email address.\r\n";
                        break;
                    case "telephone":
                        errmsg += "Please enter a contact number.\r\n";
                        break;
                    case "comments":
                        errmsg += "Please tell us why you are the fun, energetic person that we are looking for.\r\n";
                        break;
                    case "upload":
                        errmsg += "Please upload your CV so that we can review it.";
                        break;
                }
                event.returnValue = false;
                alert(errmsg);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm not very familiar with `.each()` so I can't be sure myself if I got it right. Currently this code still allows form submission to go through and doesn't alert with anything even if there are empty fields.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? $.browser is deprecated.

Comment: Looks like oldest referenced in the page is 1.8.1. If deprecated, what's the preferred method here?

Comment: $.support() is what is used to determine if a browser supports a curent method. I set up a fiddle with your code and the HTML5 keeps the form from being submitted without having to resort to JavaScript or jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/LRFbR/

Comment: I know the HTML5 keeps the form from being submitted, but this is a > IE9 solution and I need to support all the way back to IE7 as well

Comment: Ah. One method would be to grey out the submit button until all fields are filled in.

Comment: Maybe stupid comment, but shouldn't it be if ($(this).val() == "")   (with parenthesis after .val)

Comment: jbl you make a good point and I've adjusted the working code (will update the question in a bit) as per your suggestion because that would cause an error. It didn't change the way the form behaves though.

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work :

- fixed some syntax errors with parenthesis and curly bracket (markup for the textarea has double close '/' too)
- replaced the $.browser.msie which is not supported since jquery 1.9 with `navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i)` (testing for support of the `required` attribute might be even better)

  ```
  $("form[name=upload]").submit(function() {      
  // Internet Explorer uses a different call to stop form submission
  // so we need to determine which browser is being used.

  // DOM compliant browsers use HTML5 to do this.

  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i))
  {
      $("form[name=upload] input").each(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == "")
          {
              var target, errmsg;
              switch ($(this).attr("name"))
              {
                  case "first_name":
                      errmsg += "Please enter your name.\r\n";
                      break;
                  case "email":
                      errmsg += "Please enter your email address.\r\n";
                      break;
                  case "telephone":
                      errmsg += "Please enter a contact number.\r\n";
                      break;
                  case "comments":
                      errmsg += "Please tell us why you are the fun, energetic person that we are looking for.\r\n";
                      break;
                  case "upload":
                      errmsg += "Please upload your CV so that we can review it.";
                      break;
              }
              event.returnValue = false;
              alert(errmsg);
          }
      });
      }
  });
  ```

Hope this will help

Comment: How will this work with jquery 1.8.x? I'm not using 1.9 on this page

Comment: @Ortund This should work with 1.8 too. (BTW don't forget to init your error message to empty string)

Comment: The form submission still goes through :/ I think there's a flaw in my logic here

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I took the easy way out and surrounded my script block with a conditional statement:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Do jquery validation here...
</script>
<![endif]-->
```